# Is there a way to merge boolean value fields in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains several fields with Boolean values.

I need 3 of the fields to be merged into one only if all 3 of them are true.

I was thinking about a `JOIN`, but it looks like it cannot do what I need.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| Email address| permission1 | permission2 | permission3
------------------------------------------------------------
| test@test.com|     1       |      0      |      1
------------------------------------------------------------
| test2@test.com|     1      |      1      |      1
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would expect a result, perhaps in a new table to look like this:

```
--------------------------------
| Email address| permissionMerge 
--------------------------------
| test@test.com|     0       | 
--------------------------------
| test2@test.com|     1      | 
--------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are looking for? i.e. provide an example of the the original data and what you want the query results to look like.

Comment: Write the database schema please to help you

Comment: You may probably can do it with the MySQL case command.  So, you will select the case returning 0 or 1.

Comment: @kojow7 I have updated my question, please take a look :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [CASE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)

```
SELECT `email address`,
CASE WHEN `permission1` = 1 
     AND  `permission2` = 1 
     AND `permission3` = 1 
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END AS 'permissionMerge'
FROM `Table`
```

You could also do it that way:

```
SELECT `email address`,
CASE WHEN SUM(`permission1`,`permission2`,`permission3`) = 3   
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END AS 'permissionMerge'
FROM `Table`
GROUP BY `email address`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select `Email adderss`,(permission1 and permission2 and permission3) as permissionMerge from table
```

Comment: FYI, this doesn't normally work in other database engines like Oracle or SQL Server but it works fine in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the quality of data, you could get away with something as simple as:

```
SELECT address,
CASE SUM(permission1, permission2, permission3)
    WHEN 3 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS permissionMerge 
FROM undisclosed_table
```

... or you'll need something more robust:

```
SELECT address,
CASE
    WHEN permission1 IS TRUE AND permission2 IS TRUE AND permission3 IS TRUE THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS permissionMerge 
FROM undisclosed_table
```

You can generate a new table with:

```
CREATE TABLE table_with_duplicate_data
SELECT address,
CASE
    WHEN permission1 IS TRUE AND permission2 IS TRUE AND permission3 IS TRUE THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS permissionMerge 
FROM undisclosed_table
```

... thought I'd advise against it: it'll just waste storage and you need to keep data up-to-date. If it's too much typing, you can create a [view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) or (since MySQL/5.7.5) a [generated column](http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/).